# Can the integral of a Gaussian change when rotated?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, python

Consider the general 2D Gaussian function, centered at (0.5,0.5),

`A*exp(-a*(-0.5 + x)**2-b*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-c*(-0.5 + y)**2)`

where the covariance matrix can be written in terms of the coefficients a,b, and c as

\begin{pmatrix}
2a  & b\\
b & 2c
\end{pmatrix}

Rotating by 45 degrees counterclockwise gives

$$\frac{2}{4}\left( \begin{array}{rr} 1 & -1\\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2a & b\\ b & 2c\end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{rr} 1 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right)= \cdots =\left(\begin{array} ((a-b+c) & (a-c)\\(a-c) & (a+b+c)\end{array}\right)$$

However, given a=1.25, b=0 and c=10000, and using Python to integrate over the unit square,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=1.25
b=0   
c=10000
d=(a-b+c)/2
e=a-c
f=(a+b+c)/2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x,y=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,50),np.linspace(0,1,50))
z=3*np.exp(-a*(-0.5 + x)**2-b*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-c*(-0.5 + y)**2)
w=3*np.exp(-d*(-0.5 + x)**2-e*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-f*(-0.5 + y)**2) #rotated by 45 degrees counterclockwise
cs=ax.contour(x,y,z,levels=[0.8],colors='k',linestyles='dashed');
cs=ax.contour(x,y,w,levels=[0.8],colors='k',linestyles='dashed');

from scipy import integrate
h = lambda y, x: 3*np.exp(-a*(-0.5 + x)**2-b*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-c*(-0.5 + y)**2)
g = lambda y, x: 3*np.exp(-d*(-0.5 + x)**2-e*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-f*(-0.5 + y)**2)
print(integrate.dblquad(h, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1))
print(integrate.dblquad(g, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1))
```

And output:

```
(0.061757213121080706, 1.4742783672680448e-08)
(0.048117567144166894, 5.930455188853047e-12)
```

As well as (where the one with coefficients a,b,c is the horizontal one, and the level curves are for C=z(x,y)=w(x,y)=0.8):

[image: Rotated vs. Non-rotated]

Comment: I don't know enough Python to follow precisely what you're doing there.  But certainly if you rotate a function in the plane and you don't also rotate the domain of integration (as your figure makes it appear), you shouldn't expect the integral to remain the same.

Comment: How does this follow in terms of linear algbra? One rotates the covariance matrix and possibly the means, but why should one also rotate the integration domain?

Comment: And if possible, how does one find a rotated Gaussian, for the horizontal level curve in the figure for example, that does give the same integral, so one can plot both of them in one figure?

Comment: For your first question: your original integration domain was something like $0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1$.  When you apply your linear transformations to $x$ and $y$, you get something like $0 \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x + y) \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x - y) \leq 1$ (more or less—check the signs on these expressions before using.)   I don't understand what you're asking in your second question.

Comment: How do you solve such a system of inequalities? I'd like to plot the level curves of the rotated and non-rotated function. Currently I'm using the same grid to plot these level curves with, but presumably that has to change too, since clearly they don't match.

Comment: I get $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}/2 \leq y \leq \sqrt{2}/2$, but the integrals are still different.